# Expand Ubuntu OpenStack cloud

Tags: maas, openstack, conjure-up

I'm use MaaS + conjure-up to install my Ubuntu OpenStack cloud in 8 servers. But now i purshase another server, how can I add to the OpenStack Cloud?